# Windows azure blob: the remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: azure-storage

Please look when i browse 
[image: http://127.0.0.1:10050/devstoreaccount1/]

and 
[image: http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/]

and when I excecute the command DSInit /forceCreate it display below window I have hard time find where from these old port are running see in the original question I have changed the port to 10050 and I see the same when in execute **DSServiceLDB** i,e 10050, 10051, 10052

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are running the storage server (storage explorer) locallly and that is running on the ports you have mentioned here. Also follow all the steps to get the downloaded app running present here

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-web-site/2-download-and-run/

Comment: Thanks for your reply: Please see my question again

Comment: @user641812 - do not put the additional information in the answers section edit your question and add the information